# SELECT statement with JOIN and WHERE clause not returning any data

Tags: sql, winforms, datagridview

I have problem with data that needs to be seen on datagridview. Bellow is my code:

```
    Public Class Form3

    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Dim CONNECT_STRING As String = (...)

Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection(CONNECT_STRING)

        cnn.Open()

        MsgBox(status_narocila.value)

        Dim sql As String = "SELECT artikel.st_artikla, artikel.naziv_artikla, narocilo.kolicina, narocilo.barva_tiska, narocilo.izvedba, narocilo.opombe, narocilo.datum_narocila, narocilo.rok_izdelave, narocilo.status, narocilo.ID FROM (narocilo INNER JOIN artikel ON narocilo.id_artkla = artikel.ID) WHERE(narocilo.ID = '" & status_narocila.value & "')"

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, cnn)

        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

        Dim ds As New DataSet

        da.Fill(ds, "artikel")

        cnn.Close()

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("artikel")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Value `status.narocila.value` is integer, I've tested it and getting right value from it. The code is working fine without `WHERE` clause.

Comment: try to `.ToString()` → `status_narocila.value.ToString()`

Comment: Shouldn't need a space WHERE( to WHERE (.  I'm more inclined to believe you don't need the ' if ID is a numeric data type.  So what is the data type of narocilo.ID?

Comment: What is the database type of the field narocilo.ID ?

Comment: Have you tested and put break point after the sql string. And run it in SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

```
= '" & status_narocila.value & "')"
```

should be

```
= " & status_narocila.value & ")"
```

no ' on numeric data types.

Answer (score 0):

If `narocilo.ID` is also an integer, then the problem is you're using text qualifers on an integer field.

Try changing your WHERE clause to:

`WHERE(narocilo.ID = " & status_narocila.value & ")"`